# Do pre-boot software keyloggers exist?

Tags: keyloggers, bitlocker

Let's sat for example that I have a laptop with just one hard drive running Windows 10. The Laptop's C:\ (boot) drive is encrypted using Bitlocker, and it set up to ask for a PIN on start to decrypt the drive and load the OS.

Is there such a thing (or would it be theoretically possible) as a purely software keylogger that could record the bitlocker PIN after a cold boot?

We are looking at security cases for USB drive vs PIN bitlocker unlocking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they exist (like this Russian one [uefilog on github](https://github.com/hummelchen/uefilog)
Also Hardware key loggers would capture this information.
And in theory one could implement an hardware keylogger in the BIOS itself.

How likely they are is a different matter. in most cases its easier to capture this information through other means. (side-channel, social engineering, Hardware key-logger, etc).

But this is one of the use-cases for Smart-card readers with separated numbered keyboard .

Comment: Thank you - It would be great (if you know) if you could expand a bit on how such a software logger manages to run itself pre-boot on an encrypted system, does it live in the MBR?

Comment: the one in the link is running in the UEFI. so it attached itself to th EUFI loader that is NOT encrypted with the rest of the volume.

Comment: Would Secure Boot mitigate the threat to the unencrypted portion of the boot volume?

Comment: Not really, since the UEFI modules can be loaded in some systems regardless of what you boot. (and it could be signed to work even if it does require it)